# fzf: ctlr-r not triggering history search on command line

Tags: fzf

I've installed fzf on debian 11 (bullseye). When I type in ctrl-r to trigger a history search, nothing happens. Works fine on my mac. I'm using zsh.

UPDATE: tried adding `bindkey '^r' fzf-history-widget` to .zshrc but I just get a "no such widget" error.

fzf --version reports 0.24 (devel)

Comment: history | fzf does the job. No great need for keybinding or plugins.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OK, found the answer at https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/fzf which says to refer to README file:

```
Bash
====

Append this line to ~/.bashrc to enable fzf keybindings for Bash:

   source /usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/key-bindings.bash

Append this line to ~/.bashrc to enable fuzzy auto-completion for Bash:

   source /usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/completion.bash

Zsh
===

Append this line to ~/.zshrc to enable fzf keybindings for Zsh:

   source /usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/key-bindings.zsh

Append this line to ~/.zshrc to enable fuzzy auto-completion for Zsh:

   source /usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/completion.zsh

Fish
====

Issue the following commands to enable fzf keybindings for Fish:

   mkdir -p ~/.config/fish/functions/
   echo fzf_key_bindings > ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish

Vim
===

The straightforward way to use fzf.vim is appending this line to your vimrc:

   source /usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/fzf.vim
```

Comment: and `fish_user_key_bindings.fish` should contain the function, as declared here: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.fish

Comment: In archlinux the path is

`/usr/share/fzf/key-bindings.bash`

Answer (score 3):

This plugin also does the trick either via `zinit` or `oh-my-zsh`
https://github.com/joshskidmore/zsh-fzf-history-search

Comment: yes this plugin works, but i had to install fzf again using $sudo apt install fzf

Answer (score 0):

This might not be relevant to this stack exchange, but on an M1 mac, I found the `key-bindings.zsh` file in: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fzf/0.36.0/shell/key-bindings.zsh`.

By adding this file to my `.zshrc` I was able to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> working with `fzf`.